# Inno Setup uninstall executable location and name

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

Can I configure it to be placed in the same location `C:\windows\something\` that .msi files produced by windows installer are hidden in, instead of in `C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder\`?

Also can I change the name to something more obvious in intent than unins000.exe?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The uninstaller path can be changed by setting a value in the script file:

```
[Setup]
UninstallFilesDir={win}\Installer
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to change the name.

Answer (score 4):

With the shipping InnoSetup there is currently no way specify the Uninstall file name.

Since Source is available you can change the behavior the file name is stored
in UninstallExeFileName and is set in GenerateFilenames() in the Install.pas

Comment: Probably overkill in my case.  Out of curiosity though, does borland offer a free Delphi compiler or would I have to buy one to make the change?

Comment: There is currently no Free Compiler